# Python | Web-scraping user review

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm taking the first steps in webscraping but probably I have chosen a "difficult" problem

I'm trying to download user ratings in this site (5 stars, 4 stars, ets) https://www.influenster.com/ but instead, I have the review date.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.influenster.com/reviews/ferrero-rocher-chocolate")

rating = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".hXWPE.ixyxcj")
rating_text = [t.text for t in rating]
rating_text
```

Output

```
['April 11th 2020, 9:49 pm',
 'April 16th 2020, 9:30 pm',
 'March 16th 2020, 10:32 am',
 'December 22nd 2019, 2:13 am',
 'March 31st 2020, 2:02 am',
 'April 11th 2020, 7:10 pm',
 'April 12th 2020, 2:13 pm',
 'May 15th 2020, 6:00 am',
 'April 13th 2020, 7:39 pm',
 'January 23rd 2020, 4:02 pm']
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: it seems you use wrong selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates also satisfy that css selector and as they're before the comment they are being returned first.

Try the following:

```
rating = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("review-text")
```

For the author and stars...

```
ratings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ixyxcj>.fNRjgH")
for rating in ratings:
    author = rating.find_element_by_css_selector('.author-card .name').text
    stars = rating.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ixyxcj .productComponents__SingleStar-sc-1ffpes9-3.kdXCBs')
    print('The author: ' + author + ' gave ' + str(len(stars)) + ' stars')
```

Comment: Hi Prab G. This works for review text but not for rating stars (5 stars, 4 stars)

Comment: I've added some more code that will get you the stars. It looks like given stars have a different classname (kdXCBs) then the greyed out stars. Each star is represented by a <div> so you''ll have to work with the count. See the example.